# Problemas com PDO

Tags: php, pdo

Sou novo com PHP e gostaria de tirar uma dúvida:

No código que mostrarei abaixo, foi testada a consulta no banco até o `try`, o problema é que após o `try(){}` o prepare não me retorna nada, eu testei com o `die('');` e ele só me retorna os `echo` e só vai até ai.

Segue o código login.php

```
<?php
require_once("connect.php");
//recuperar dados
if(isset($_POST['logar'])){
    echo 'clciou</br>';
    echo   $usuario= trim(strip_tags($_POST['usuario']));
    echo   $senha= trim(strip_tags($_POST['senha']));
    $select="SELECT*FROM login WHERE usuario=:usuario AND senha=:senha";
    echo $contar = $selec-> rowCount();
    try{
        $result = $conexao ->prepare($select);
        $result -> bindParam(':usuario',$usuario,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $result -> bindParam(':senha',$senha,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $result -> execute();
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e;
    }
}
?>
```

Formulário que ele pega

```
<form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <h1>Faça seu Login</h1>
  <div class="login-fields">
    <p>Entre com seus dados:</p>
    <div class="field">
      <label for="username">Usuário:</label>
      <input type="text" id="username" name="usuario" value="" placeholder="Usuário" class="login username-field" />
    </div>
    <!-- /field -->
    <div class="field">
      <label for="password">Senha:</label>
      <input type="password" id="password" name="senha" value="" placeholder="Senha" class="login password-field" />
    </div>
    <!-- /password -->
  </div>
  <!-- /login-fields -->
  <div class="login-actions">
    <input type="submit" name="logar" value="entrar no sistema" class="button btn btn-success btn-large" />
  </div>
  <!-- .actions -->
</form>
```

Alguém poderia me indicar o que eu faço de errado?

Comment: Veja se assim aparece algum erro: `if(! $result -> execute()){ print_r($result->errorInfo());`

Comment: Editei o post pra ficar mais fácil de entender.

Comment: Obrigado marcelo, mas assim, eu usei e ele não me informou nada.

Comment: O erro que deu foi esse : Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in /var/www/html/chris/login.php

Comment: Você instanciou o $conexao ? no caso deve ser umas instancia do PDO, tem como colocar como esta a classe connect.php?

Comment: Olá garoto! Para que isso? "echo   $usuario= trim(strip_tags($_POST['usuario']));" e isso? " echo   $senha= trim(strip_tags($_POST['senha']));" Tu queres usar a variável ou imprimí-la? O certo seria: $usuario= trim(strip_tags($_POST['usuario'])); e $senha= trim(strip_tags($_POST['senha']));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá garoto olha ai a solução:

```
<?php
require_once("connect.php");

//recuperar dados
if(isset($_POST['logar']) == true){
echo 'clicou</br>';
//Melhor seria usar Expressões regulares aqui, é mais seguro        
//seria bom também passar o htmlentities($var, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8', false)
// nos campos e converter tudo para utf-8, o "false" diz à função que
// não tente converte se já estiver no formato utf-8
$usuario= trim(strip_tags($_POST['usuario']));
$senha= trim(strip_tags($_POST['senha']));

// Executar a instrução SQL     
$sql = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE nome = :usuario AND senha = :senha";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':usuario', $usuario,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':senha', $senha,PDO::PARAM_STR);

$stmt->execute();
// Se encontrar algumacoisa '$stmt->rowCount() > 0', continuar
if($stmt->rowCount() > 0 ){

//Percorrendo todos os registros encontrados
for($i=0; $row = $stmt->fetch(); $i++){
//Imprime o ID e nome do Usuário                
echo "O id &eacute;:".$row['id'].", o nome &eacute;:".$row['nome']."<br />";
}
} else {
//Caso não encontre nada escreva "Nadinha!" ou algo mais inteligente
echo "Nadinha!";
}
}
?>
```

Esse tray fica no connect. Eutentei desse jeito ai e não vai de jeito nenhum.
Em relação a esse arquivo "connect.php", ele deveria ser exatamente assim:

```
<?php
//File connect.php
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=nomedoseudatabase';
$user = 'usuariododatabase';
$password = 'senhadosusuariododatabase'; 
try {
//instaciar o objeto PDO    
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
// adicionar suporte a utf-8
$pdo->exec("SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci'");
//dizer ao pdo o que fazer em caso de erro
} catch (PDOException $e) {echo 'Conexao sem sucesso: ' . $e->getMessage(); }
?>
```

Tive que fazer essa tabela no db do meu Slackware aqui para testar, ta funcionando direitinho.

Eu acho que tu deverias ter por hábito fazer uma classe para o database ou classes. No meu site uso vários database, os usuários, sessions e perfis e preferencias do usuário ficam em um mesmo database. Já postagens e outras coisas que são colocadas no site ficam em outro e tudo funciona redondinho. Ele pega os posts e, ao correr sobre cada post ele consulta o outro database e pega tudo sobre o usuário, inclusive redes sociais se ele cadastrou e coloca os schemas no post para indexação no Google.
Se o cara estiver logando ele consulta inclusive a tabela de perfil automaticamente pois a classe de login chama a classe de perfil a qual verifica se a pessoa tem perfil no site e se tiver coloca todas as preferencias do usuário na session e isso pode ser acessado por todo o site para que ele não precise mais colocar nome em formulários, pois nem há campos para nome e emails se a pessoa estiver logada.
Classes simplifica muito as coisas.
Abração garoto! Bons estudos!